# Javascript Transaction object Message versus Tag

Tags: transaction, iri-legacy-api, javascript

What is the difference between the Message and Tag values when creating a new transaction object via the JS library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Tag` field is short and can be used to search transactions (so you can search the tangle for transactions with tag "GUS9GORMAN", but not for transactions with message "GUS9GORMAN"). The `Message` field is longer; but for transactions that spend iota (which is internally represented by a negative `Value`), the message needs to contain the signature so that the transaction can get confirmed (so you can only fill it with custom data for transactions that either receive iota or zero value transactions).

Comment: @bernd The negative value is correct. Transactions where the address receive iota have a positive value, and when the address spends iota, they have a negative value. Transactions that do not move iota have a zero value.